# Use camera for capture photo in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, flutter-web

Im currently using this article : https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera for capture photo on android and it works fine,
also when i run my debug web app it will open the camera to take picture but when i `build web` , the camera won't open to capture photo!
does any body face this problem ever?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you're serving the web application over HTTPS (or localhost for local development). From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/camera_web) accessing camera devices require a secure browsing context.  For insecure contexts CameraPlatform.availableCameras might throw a CameraException with the permissionDenied error code.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you followed the documentation of `camera` plugin for web implementations too. There are some [limitations](https://pub.dev/packages/camera_web#limitations-on-the-web-platform) of camera for web

For displaying the picture the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/camera_web) states

The web platform does not support `dart:io`. Attempts to display a captured image using `Image.file` will throw an error. The capture image contains a network-accessible URL pointing to a location within the browser (blob) and can be displayed using `Image.network` or `Image.memory` after loading the image bytes to memory.

See the example below:

```dart
if (kIsWeb) {
  Image.network(capturedImage.path);
} else {
  Image.file(File(capturedImage.path));
}
```

Comment: thank you for ur response , my problem is that i cant even open the camera , not display the captured image. i followed capture image using camera plugin(the link i mentioned), is that enough? because i know this plugin is endorsed

Comment: @NavidShokoufe are you putting camera_web in dev dependencies in pubsec file?

Comment: no actually i didn't ! i find out camera plugin is an endorsed plugin and thought its not necessary to add camera_web to dependency. should i add that?

Comment: Have you read the limitations?