# Cannot get image from camera Flutter web

Tags: flutter, image, camera

I'm new to Flutter. With flutter web I'm trying to make a web application that allows me to use the camera. I want to be able to detect the user's face. I have a flask code that takes care of this, but to do so it needs a series of images that I'd like to send it from flutter. When I try to retrieve the image, it returns a blob link that opens another window to my application. So I can't retrieve the image.
I've tried image picker web, imagepicker, camera as plugins but I still have the same problem.

here I initialize the camera :

```
startCamera() async {
  _cameras = await availableCameras();
  _controller = CameraController(_cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.high, enableAudio: false);
  _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  _controller.initialize().then((_) {
  // _controller.startImageStream(image);
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }).catchError((Object e) {
    if (e is CameraException) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case 'CameraAccessDenied':
          // Handle access errors here
          break;
        default:
          // Handle other errors here
          break;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

This is the code that takes the picture in the Onpress method of a button:

```
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
// Ensure that the camera is initialized.
await _initializeControllerFuture;
// Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
// where it was saved.
final image = await _controller.takePicture();
var selected = io.File(image.path);
                          
print("this is the selected path" + image.path);
```

This is what i get in the console :

`this is the selected path blob:http://localhost:49318/bdd2-002c0374c3c6`

can you please help me? I've been working on it for several days now

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly. So you retrieve the image as the blob format because it is an Image from the web. As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73483394/9202669), the web platform does not support the `dart:io` package. To Display it you'll need to use

```
Image.Network(blobPath)
```

When u want to save the image, you need to decode the image to [BASE64](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/base64Decode.html).
So you'll get something like:

```
Uint8List image = base64.decode(blobPath)
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the image.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'm trying to take pictures using the camera and display them. When I use image.network it returns nothing as if the link was empty. And when I use base64 decode it gives me an error "FormatException: Invalid character (at character 5)
blob:http://localhost:49318/56a12b3f-17ad-4d3c-977d-b4e3e3130027"

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

1. Decode the captured image to `ui.image`:

   ```dart
   XFile file = await controller!.takePicture();
   final data = await file.readAsBytes();
   ui.Image sourceImage = await decodeImageFromList(data);
   ```
2. Draw the `ui.image` with `CustomPainter`:

   ```dart
   class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
      ui.Image? image;

      MyPainter (this.image);

      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
       final paint = Paint()
       ..color = colorOrange
       ..strokeWidth = 15
       ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

       if (image != null) {
         canvas.drawImage(image!, Offset.zero, paint);
       }

     }

     @override
     bool shouldRepaint(OverlayPainter oldDelegate) => true;
   }
   ```
3. Render a `CustomPaint` widget with `MyPainter`:

   ```dart
   FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        child: SizedBox(
            width: image!.width.toDouble(),
            height: image.height.toDouble(),
            child: CustomPaint(
                painter: MyPainter(image),
    )));
   ```

You can also try my [source code](https://github.com/yushulx/flutter-document-scanner) and [online demo](https://yushulx.me/flutter-document-scanner/).